# Explain why a series solution for $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-v^2)y=0$ obtained by the method of Frobenius will converge for $ 0<x<\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The linear second-order differential equation $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-v^2)y=0$ (3.2.1)
where $v\ge 0$ is a fixed parameter,is called Bessel’s equation of order $v$. This equation has a regular singular point at $x = 0$ and no other singular points in the complex plane.

**Explain why a series solution for (3.2.1) obtained by the method of Frobenius will converge for $0 < x <\infty$.**
The indicial equation for (3.2.1) is
$$r(r-1)+r-v^2=(r-v)(r+v)=0$$
which has roots $r_1 = v$ and $r_2 = -v$. If  $r_1 - r_2 = 2v$ is not an integer, then the method of
Frobenius yields two linearly independent solutions, given by 
$$y_1(x)=a_0 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2_n}n!(1+v)_n}x^{2n+v},(3.2.2)$$
$$y_2(x)=b_0 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2_n}n!(1-v)_n}x^{2n-v},(3.2.3)$$

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics StackExchange! What's your question?

Comment: click the bessel's equation

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. Please read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask to understand MSE standard for questions, and https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation on how to format mathematical expression. As it stands, your question will likely be closed (do not insert links, there are no clear question, no background,...)